# REAL basename vs PHP basename (pathinfo)

Tags: php, naming-conventions, filenames, pathinfo

I've got for example a watermark file: `ROOT.'/media/watermarks/1.jpg'`.

In the future user can use (in some custom php template system) for example: `'watermark-filename'`, `'watermark-basename'`, , `'watermark-directory'`, etc to get needed data.

I'm trying to create some reasonable global variables names.

---

The question is, what does really 'basename' mean?

Terminal:

```
basename /path/to/source/file.ext -> "file"
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    echo basename('/path/to/source/file.ext'); // file.ext

    $path_parts = pathinfo('/path/to/source/file.ext');
    echo $path_parts['basename']; // file.ext
?>
```

Wikipedia:

> Many file systems, including FAT, NTFS, and VMS systems, allow a filename extension that consists of one or more characters following the last period in the filename, dividing the **filename** into two parts: **a basename or stem and an extension or suffix** used by some applications to indicate the file type.

I know Wikipedia is not a source, but according to my best knowledge, **in operating systems**

```
filename = file.ext
basename = file
extension = ext
```

While in **php**:

```
filename = file
basename = file.ext
extension = ext
```

Why?

Comment: So, the denomination is arbitrary. How is your question related to variable names now?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I'm trying to make a consistent naming on my whole system, and I cannot decide which one to use. I thought it is arbitrary, but is there any reason why php use such a strange naming? PHP is based on C, where basename is also "normal". Was someone drunk while writing it? :)

Comment: Unix filesystems don't actually have a concept of filename extensions. They're just used decoratively, or interpreted at the application level. (Apache for example interprets multiple "extensions" even). The POSIX `basename` function also just splits dirname from paths; as does the `basename` command line tool, which PHPs `basename()` function is modeled after.

Comment: OK. I think this is worth the answer, as all my doubts are dispelled now. Please, post an answer with possible sources, and I will accept it :). Thanks for Your time and help.